# double coset decomposition of $U_\beta\setminus GL_n(E)/ U_\beta$ over p-adic field

Tags: p-adic-groups

Let $E/F$ be a quadratic extension of local fields. Let $\beta$ be a non degenerate Hermitian matrix of rank $n$, and let $U_\beta$ be the unitary group defined by $\beta$. Do we have an explicit double coset decomposition 
$$U_\beta\setminus GL_n(E)/U_\beta?$$

If $E/F=\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta=1_n$, then this is just the Cartan decomposition. In this case, we can choose diagonal matrices as a set of representatives of this double coset.

Do we have a similar result in the p-adic field case? In particular, can we expect that the symmetric matrices form a set of representatives of this double coset?

Comment: In contrast with archimedean $F$, where (conjugates of) a definite unitary group are the maximal compact subgroups of the group ${\rm{GL}}_n(E)$ of $F$-points of the Weil restriction ${\rm{R}}_{E/F}({\rm{GL}}_n)$, in the non-archimedean case the maximal compact subgroups are (conjugates of) ${\rm{GL}}_n(O_E)$; i.e., it has nothing to do with unitary groups (reasonable, since there are no anisotropic hermitian or quadratic forms over non-archimedean $F$ in more than a few variables). There is a Cartan decomposition, but it has nothing to do with hermitian forms. What is your motivation?

Comment: You are right. But I just want to know this double coset decomposition. The connection with archimedian case might be misleading. One motivation is linear algebra. Goldstein and Guralnick http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869306004091 give a double coset decomposition of $Sp_{2n}\setminus GL_{2n}/Sp_{2n}$ over arbitrary field. It is natural to ask the above question after their results.

Comment: The other motivation is that I want to know if it is always true that a matrix A and its transpose AT are always in the same double coset of $U_\beta∖GL_n(E)/U_\beta$. See another post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/191747/a-unitary-relation-between-a-matrix-and-its-transpose